# Python Find text in all files in a folder (like grep -rl text )

Tags: python

Hello how could i approach the following problem with Python?
Find text in all files in a folder (similar to grep -rl "text" directory)

Answer (score 0):

Captain Harlock You can directly call same command by python using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), system, [popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/popen2.html) modules 
subprocess.call(["grep", "-l", "-r"])

and of course you can write same in python by processing files text, however it would not be the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! Can i use an element like the list[0] from a list which includes a string i would like to search?

Comment: I have done it this way. Although the script terminates with  <subprocess.Popen object at 0x0282F170>. I have inserted p.communicate() but with no luck. It seems that it needs more time to wait

Comment: Changed to p = subprocess.check_call(['grep','-l','-r', a, '*']) and everything is ok now!!!!